# Is there a simple way to swap rows in a matrix to form identity matrix on left side

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, sorting

Given a matrix, A, that can be square, but, is most likely rectangular; and given that an identity matrix can be formed on the Rank(A) left most columns, is there a nice way to row swap to achieve this identity matrix?

For example, starting with

```
import numpy as np
row1 = np.array([1, 0, 0, 2, 3])
row2 = np.array([0, 0, 1, 4, 5])
row3 = np.array([0, 1, 0, 6, 7])
A = np.array([row1, row2, row3])
```

I would like to have

```
row1 = np.array([1, 0, 0, 2, 3])
row2 = np.array([0, 1, 0, 6, 7])
row3 = np.array([0, 0, 1, 4, 5])
A = np.array([row1, row2, row3])
```

I would like for this to be general, more than 1 row may need to be swapped, and there is no limit to the size of the matrix. Nor is there any guarantee the swap will be neighboring rows. Time does not matter i.e., efficiency is not important. Columns will not need to be swapped. The columns making up the Rank(A) identity matrix will on the left side.

A harder "test case" is

```
row1 = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 5, 6, 7])
row2 = np.array([0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 4, 2])
row3 = np.array([0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 6, 8, 4])
row4 = np.array([0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1])
row5 = np.array([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 8, 4])
A = np.array([row1, row2, row3, row4, row5])
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swap two rows in a numpy array in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069863/swap-two-rows-in-a-numpy-array-in-python)

Comment: See my answer. Lmk if you'd like more explanation.

Comment: Is the matrix guaranteed to have full rank, or do we have to deal with cases where, say, the input is a 4x5 matrix with rank 3?

Comment: I have pruned the matrix so that it has full rank, at this point

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the shuffled-identity part of A is a unitary matrix.

And because of properties of permutations of the identity matrix, that means you can simply multiply `A` by `A[:rows, :rows].T` (the identity perm part):

```
rows = 3 # the number of rows

A = A[:rows, :rows].T.dot(A)
```

Result; `A =` :

```
array([[1, 0, 0, 2, 3],
       [0, 1, 0, 6, 7],
       [0, 0, 1, 4, 5]])
```

Who's rows are switched to form the identity.

Comment: This doesn't work for the following case 'row1 = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 5, 6, 7])
row2 = np.array([0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 4, 2])
row3 = np.array([0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 6, 8, 4])
row4 = np.array([0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1])
row5 = np.array([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 8, 4])
A = np.array([row1, row2, row3, row4, row5])
rows = 5
A = A[:rows, :rows].dot(A)'

Comment: This has a worse time complexity than a more "direct" shuffle based on copying rows where they need to go, but the questioner *did* say they don't care about efficiency. I'd be a bit worried about rounding error with some matrix multiplication algorithms when the input is floating point, though.

Comment: I don't know how to make that nicer, but all I did was add 2 rows, and jumble them up a bit

Comment: @GeorgeK try it now I forgot to transpose.

Comment: Yes, very nice. I should have been able to spot that as well.

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution, but it might be (very) unoptimised. Keeping in mind that this solution is dependent on the number of rows corresponding to the length of the identity matrix:

```
def find_RankA(arr):
    identity_len = arr.shape[0]
    new_arr = np.empty_like(arr)
    for row in arr:
        replacement_index = row[:identity_len].tolist().index(1)
        new_arr[replacement_index] = row
    return new_arr

if __name__ == '__main__':
    row1 = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 5, 6, 7])
    row2 = np.array([0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 4, 2])
    row3 = np.array([0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 6, 8, 4])
    row4 = np.array([0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1])
    row5 = np.array([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 8, 4])
    A = np.array([row1, row2, row3, row4, row5])
    print(find_RankA(A))

(Feedback welcome)
```

We can shorten the function to:

```
def find_RankA(arr):
    new_arr = np.empty_like(arr)
    for row in arr:
        new_arr[row[:arr.shape[0]].tolist().index(1)] = row
    return new_arr
```

Answer (score 1):

Obligatory sorting based method:

```
A[np.argsort(np.argmax(A[:,:len(A)], 1))]
```